# VOIP which is support JINGLE_NODE in android

Tags: android, voip, libjingle

I have the basic doubts for developing VOIP which is support `JINGLE_NODE` in Android. I am following [here](https://github.com/lukeweber/webrtc-jingle-client)

1. Why we need to do the lot of steps to run the `webrtc_jingle_project` in `Android`. Why we can't run directly those three application which is in webrtc_jingle_project directory in Android.
2. Why we can't directly use the `JNI` which is in `voice_client_native` directory.